# JAVA: Export ArrayLists into excel table with NEW sheet everytime

Tags: java, excel, hssf

I have two ArraysLists (X and Y) with different number of elements. Now, i want to export them among themselves into an excel-table. X and Y should have their own columns side by side.

Example: X = [2 , 6 , 0],  Y = [5 , 8 , 3]

```
X | Y 
------
2 | 5 
6 | 8 
0 | 3
```

Everytime I run the program, the Arrays will get new elements. At the end of my programm, those has to be saved in the excel table, and everytime in a new sheet. When i open my pogramm five times, i should have five sheets (the name of my sheet is the actual time and date - its saved in a variable called date).

My questions:
1. How can i get my ArrayLists into their own colums?
2. How am i supposed to create NEW sheets and dont overwrite my old ones?

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(date); //everytime, the sheet will be overwritten, but i need a new sheed. something like workbook.addSheet(date) would be perfect

            Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
            data.put("1", new Object[] {"column 1", "column 2"});

            //maybe some kind of for-loop for my ArrayLists? Dont know

            Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
            int rownum = 0;
            for (String key : keyset) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
                int cellnum = 0;
                for (Object obj : objArr) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                    if(obj instanceof Date) 
                        cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
                    else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                        cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
                    else if(obj instanceof String)
                        cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                    else if(obj instanceof Double)
                        cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
                }
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = 
                        new FileOutputStream(new File(".//src//excel-table.xls"));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: And what's the question/problem? Edit: I think I found the question (hint: putting it into a comment in your code doesn't make it very easy to spot, so you should at least repeat it outside the code).

Comment: Your problem is that you create a new workbook every time you execute the program and then overwrite it at the end. Instead you should check if the file already exists and read it into `HSSFWorkbook` before adding a new sheet.

Comment: Sorry for that. I want to put my ArrayLists (X and Y) into his own colums. Also, even when i check if i have an workbook or not, at the point HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(date); i overwrite my old sheet. I need something like workbook.add(date).

Comment: Please add that to your question and not as a comment. It's hard to find here. Also read my other comment as you probably have a misconception of how things work.